# How to view form XML in IBM Notes Domino Designer?

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I've just conducted a search for a term in IBM Domino Designer, and in the results was one of my Application subforms. Double clicking the result, I'm taken to the raw XML definition of the subform, rather than the usual WYSIWYG view I'm used to. Double clicking the name of the subform in the Applications panes just opens up the WYSIWYG view.

How can I access the raw XML view from the user interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it - right click the form, and click **Edit with DXL**.

Answer (score 0):

You can also export it, from the same menu.
Sadly, and I never understood why, there is no way to *import* XML out of the box. That said, writing an agent to to so is almost trivial and there are plenty of examples on the www.

There are also quite a few LotusScript and Java classes to handle the xml representation of everything : forms as you saw, but also any design element, the ACL and the database properties **and** of course the documents (i.e. the data)

You can export, import, parse, transform, encapsulate in the stream of a webservice provider or digest the response to a webservice request ...

If you go the Java way of course you will be able to utilize every XML-related library on Earth.

The possibilities are endless.

Normalize the look & feel of tens of legacy apps ? No problem. What was postponed for years can be accomplished in days.

If you want to know more, I suggest the Redbook [XML Powered by Domino](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246207.html)